# Freeing disk space on Ubuntu to use in Windows

Tags: partitioning, windows, disk-usage

I have 250Gb drive on a laptop, which has Windows 7 on a 122Gb ntfs partition (which has a "boot" flag on it) and Ubuntu 12.04.1 on a 110Gb extended partition, of which the root ext4 partition is 108Gb and the swap is 1.74Gb. You can see everything in the screenshot below. 
         My question is:

1. I want to diminish the size of the linux root partition and then use that space to increase the windows partition. How do I do that?
2. Also, is it possible to increase the size of the swap partition and not do any damage? If so, how?

   I'm using GParted, and i'd say i'm pretty confident with it.

[Screenshot of my partitions](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/mypartitions.png/)

Comment: Please consider accepting your answer to mark this as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For 1), this will be tough as you will need to shrink the root FS, then the root partition, move the root partition to create a gap between the Windows partition and the extended one, then extend the Windows partition. All this is best done using a LiveCD like http://www.sysresccd.org/Download

For 2), if you have free unpartitioned HDD space then you will need to: deactivate the swap, extent the swap partition, re-format it (mkswap), re-activate the swap. You need to update the /etc/fstab file to use the right UUID of your new swap.

Comment: Just added a screenshot. I use puppy linux on a usb stick when partitioning..

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Thanks all! I did everything, and finally got to the point where there was unallocated space in between the windows and ubuntu partitions, but then GParted (in Puppy Linux) would extend the windows partition to include the unallocated space for some reason, so I ended up doing that in windows, and it worked great. Also managed to increase swap size as well.